# Analyzing Marklogic search requests

Tags: javascript, xquery, marklogic

MarkLogic provides a possibility to see how the given search expression will be processed by the index. XQuery function **xdmp:plan** is responsible for that - https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:plan

The way it works is perfectly described here - https://www.marklogic.com/blog/working-with-xdmp-plan/

My question is if there is JavaScript analog of that function? How can I analyze the queries written in JavaScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort of depends on what you are doing. But there is probably tooling in this list to match your needs depending on what you are using for your implemntation:

[cts.plan()](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.plan)

Returns an array of JavaScript objects recording information about how the given search will be processed by the index.

---

[xdmp.sqlPlan()](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp.sqlPlan)

Returns a node representing the query plan of the given SQL SELECT query.

---

[sparqlPlan()](https://docs.marklogic.com/sem.sparqlPlan)

Return a node representing the query plan of the given SPARQL query.

---

[op.explain()](https://docs.marklogic.com/op:explain)

This method returns a representation of the builtin execution plan.

- could only find xquery doc link

---

Comment: David, thank you! So for Java Script that function appears to be in cts namespace! I was searching it in xdmp...

Comment: No problem.. There are a few other gotchas like that -  such as cts.doc and not fn.doc etc